# PHP login script will only login a specific user ?

Tags: php

I have been using this login script for a long time and its quite solid but its now broken and driving me insane.

Basically the script only accepts the first MySQL row user to login , the login system will work but just for the first SQL row , it appears to ignore all of the rows ?

**global_database.php**

```
<?php 

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dealerpa_guest';
$dbpass = 'password_here';



function dbConnect($db='') {
global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass;

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
       or die('We are currently applying some major patches and fixes to our systems.        Please try again in 10 Minutes.');

if ($db!='' and !@mysql_select_db($db))
    die('We are currently applying some major patches and fixes to our systems. Please try again in 10 Minutes.');

return $dbcnx;
 }


?>
```

**global_restriction.php**

```
<?php

session_start();


include_once 'global_database.php';
include_once 'global_common.php';

$dealerUsername = isset($_POST['dealerUsername']) ? $_POST['dealerUsername'] :      $_SESSION['dealerUsername'];
$pwd = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : $_SESSION['pwd'];


if(!isset($dealerUsername)) {
?>
<html>
<body>
  <form id="dealerLogin" name="dealerLogin" method="post" action="">
<input name="dealerUsername" type="text" id="dealerUsername" size="15"   class="validate[required] text-input" />

  <input name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd" size="15" class="validate[required] text-input" />

 <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="save-button" />

</form>

<?php

exit;
 }

$_SESSION['dealerUsername'] = $dealerUsername;
$_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;

dbConnect("dealerpa_account");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dealerAccount WHERE dealerUsername = '$dealerUsername' AND    dealerPassword = md5('$pwd')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
error('A database error occurred while checking your '.
    'login details.\\nIf this error persists, please '.
    'contact us.');
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
unset($_SESSION['dealerUsername']);
unset($_SESSION['pwd']);

?>

<html>
<body>
<p>Display Login page again if password is wrong</p>
</body>
<?php
exit;
}

$dealerUsername = mysql_result($result,0,'dealerUsername');
$dealerID = mysql_result($result,0,'dealerID');
?>
```

I have checked the PHP settings and register globals is turned on , is there anything else I can try. The strange thing is only one user can login . Its like the script isn't checking the entire table and only looking at the first SQL Row.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For some reason the script has started to work again , after 5 hours reviewing code. If you see any way to improve the script so its more secure please advise.

Comment: Could it be that your host is deprecating `mysql_` and moving over to `mysqli`? FYI: It's been said so many times here on SO, that using `mysql_` is open to injection.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You need to sanitize *ALL* user input before using it in a query or use prepared statements.

Comment: you don't seem to be validating $dealerUsername or $pwd, md5 is no longer considered secure (at least in the way it's used here without salts etc), and mysql_query is deprecated

Comment: Do not suppress any error messages... Tackle them

Comment: Yes I will be improving the script to prevent SQL injections soon. Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats happening because your row index is set to 0 in `mysql_result()`.Instead of using `mysql_result` try `mysql_fetch_assoc`. It will retrieve the user info in associated array. Hope that helps.